# Доступ к полям массивов структур на Си - в чем ошибка?

Tags: c, массивы, структуры

Не могу понять, в чем ошибка

1. Есть структура, определенная через тип:

   ```
   typedef struct _PARAMDESC { // описание параметров
        struct {
            int a;
            int b;
            int c;
            int d;
            int e;
            int f;
        } in; // для ввода
        struct {
            int a;
            int b;
            int c;
            int d;
            int e;
            int f;
        } out; // для вывода
   } PARAMDESC;
   ```
2. В ОЗУ выделяется память под массив `PARAMDESC params[256]`
3. Есть еще одна структура, определенная через тип:

   ```
    typedef struct _CONTEXT { // описание контекста вызова
        int error; // причина ошибки (в т.ч. системный код ошибки)
        int id; // идентификатор объекта
        PARAMDESC (*param)[256]; // указатель на массив параметров
    } CONTEXT;
   ```
4. Есть переменная `CONTEXT ct`, на этапе инициализации которой в ее поле `ct.param` заносится указатель на массив `PARAMDESC params[256]`:

   `ct.param=&params`

Как правильно доступиться к полю `in.a` элемента массива `params` с индексом 1 через структуру `ct`?

Пробую так:

```
ct.param[1]->in.a
```

Компилятор не ругается, но указатель вычисляет неправильно. Под отладчиком вижу, что он берет содержимое `ct.param` (т.е. указатель на динамический блок памяти) и прибавляет к нему произведение индекса (1) на 12288, что ровно в 256 раз больше размера структуры `PARAMDESC` (48 байт). Т.е. за
1 элемент в данном случае он понимает весь массив из 256 структур, а не отдельный экземпляр структуры в этом массиве.

Что я не так указал при определении структур или при обращении к полю `in.a` элемента `params[1]`?

Воспроизводимый пример проблемы:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _PARAMDESC { // описание параметров
     struct {
         int a;
         int b;
         int c;
         int d;
         int e;
         int f;
     } in; // для ввода
     struct {
         int a;
         int b;
         int c;
         int d;
         int e;
         int f;
     } out; // для вывода
} PARAMDESC;

 typedef struct _CONTEXT { // описание контекста вызова
     int error; // причина ошибки (в т.ч. системный код ошибки)
     int id; // идентификатор объекта
     PARAMDESC (*param)[256]; // указатель на массив параметров
 } CONTEXT;


int main()
{
    CONTEXT ct;
    ct.param=calloc(256,sizeof(PARAMDESC));
    if (!ct.param) return 1;
    ct.param[1]->in.a=0x5555; // Здесь ошибка!!!
                              // Происходит запись по смещению +0x3000 от
                              // начала массива, а ожидается запись по
                              // смещению +0x30 байт от начала массива
    free(ct.param);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: приведите воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения** прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PARAMDESC param[256];` - это просто массив. Доступ к значению вы производите так : `param[i]`. Это равно `param[i] == *(param + i * sizeof(PARAMDESC))`

`PARAMDESC (*param)[256];` - это указатель на массив. Доступ чуток подправляете : `(* param)[i]`.

Разница в том, что `PARAMDESC` и `PARAMDESC [256]` имеют разный размер в 256 раз. В неправильном доступе получаете : `param[i] == *(param + i * sizeof(PARAMDESC[256]))`

По типам подробнее :

`PARAMDESC (*param)[256];` - указатель на массив `PARAMDESC [256]`

`* param` == `param[0]` - массив `PARAMDESC [256]` с индексом ноль

`param[i]` - другой массив `PARAMDESC [256]` с индексом `i`

`param[i]->in` == `param[i][0].in` - при команде `->` сначала массив `param[i]` преобразуется в тип `* PARAMDESC` с индексом ноль.

`(* param)[i]` == `param[0][i]` - i - ый элемент у массива с индексом ноль.

`(* param)[i].in` == `param[0][i].in` - доступ к полю правильный

Answer (score 1):

Так если param это указатель на массив, то и пишите правильно - вначале разыменовываем, а потом индексируем.

```
(*ct.param)[1].in.a=0x5555;
```

Почему это компилируется? потому что в си массивы и указатели - братья на век.